# Matrix of a linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\gamma=\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3},v_{4}\}$ ben an ordered basis of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ and $S=[v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}]$ a subspace.

Given the following linear operator $T$ on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ such that
$$T(v)=v, \forall v\in S$$
and
$$T(v_{4})=v_{1}+v_{3}$$
I have to evaluate $[T]_{\gamma}^{\gamma}$.

What I thought about was: if $v\in S$, then $T(v)=v$, so
$$T(v_{1})=v_{1},\quad T(v_{2})=v_{2},\quad T(v_{3})=v_{3}$$
and since
$$T(v_{4})=v_{1}+v_{3}$$
so
$$[T]_{\gamma}^{\gamma}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
I want to know if it's correct.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.